# how to remove a bot from a trust wallet without revoke kindly advise

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets

how to remove a bot from a trust wallet without revoke? I have a wallet that a stealing bot has been draining my money so how to stop it ?

Comment: You mean that someone got a hold of your private key of a trust wallet address and is draining the wallet every time you send funds to it? How fast is the money drained when you send funds to the address?